# "What' and 'which' difference

Tags: determiners, wh-questions

Which one of the following sentence is grammatical?

1- **What footballer** has scored the most number of goals?

2- **Which footballer** has scored the most number of goals?

Comment: As per Brad's answer, either **(the) most goals** or **the greatest/largest number of goals**. The former is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Although both are commonly used I would go with

**What footballer has scored the most goals?** (number of is not required).

Why? basically **which** is used when you are choosing between a small number of alternatives.
Which of your friends....
what student from your school...

**which**
determiner, pronoun
UK  /wɪtʃ/ US  /wɪtʃ/
which determiner, pronoun (QUESTION)

A1
**(used in questions and structures in which there is a fixed or limited set of answers or possibilities**) what one or ones:

**what**
determiner, pronoun, exclamation
UK  /wɒt/ US  /wɑːt/
what determiner, pronoun, exclamation (QUESTION)

A1
**used to ask for information about people or things**:
What time is it?
What books did you buy?
What did you wear?
What size shoes do you take?
What happened after I left?

all ref CED [WHAT](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what)